# invalid use of incomplete type, not a namespace error

Tags: c++, class, c++14

Here is the error message

```
points.cpp:17:35: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::Point>, std::Point>::value_type’ {aka ‘class std::Point’}
         os << "(" << (pointvect[x].getx()) << "," << (pointvect[x].gety()) << ")" << "\n" ;
```

Here is the class def/dec

```
class Point
{
private:
    int x_coordinate;
    int y_coordinate;
public:
    Point(){setx(0); sety(0);}
    Point(int x, int y) { setx(x); sety(y);}
    void setx(int x){
        x_coordinate = x;

    }
    void sety(int y){
        y_coordinate = y;
    }
    const int getx(){
        return x_coordinate;
    }
    const int gety(){
        return y_coordinate;
    }
    ~Point();

    friend std::ostream& std::operator<<( ostream& os , Point point);
    
};
```

I honestly don't know what's going on, I pasted forward declarations around everywhere to CMA and I am not sure what this error means or where I am going wrong ( I have checked the class syntax several times but I am brand new so there may be some egregious error that I am simply missing).

Thanks!

ADD -
sorry, forgot the code that's actually drawing the error

```
std::ostream& std::operator<<( ostream& os , std::vector<Point>& pointvect){
    for( int x = 0; x < pointvect.size(); ++x){
        os << "(" << (pointvect[x].getx()) << "," << (pointvect[x].gety()) << ")" << "\n" ;
    }
}


namespace std {
    class Point;
    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os , vector<Point>& pointvect);

}
```

(only messed with std here because there was an obscure error about defining overloads in STD that the compiler was rejecting on standard grounds)

EDIT:

```
points.cpp:15:75: error: ‘std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream&, std::vector<Point>&)’ should have been declared inside ‘std’
 std::ostream& std::operator<<( ostream& os , std::vector<Point>& pointvect){
```

so this is what i was attempting to fix by moving the overload into STD, and the class def above by itself is generating this.

Comment: What is `pointvect`? How did `std::` get into `std::Point`? What is CMA?

Comment: Can you post a [mre] please? Did you maybe mess with the `std` namespace?

Comment: I guess it should be `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Point);`.

Comment: Why do you want to put `operator<<` into the `std` namespace? You are [not allowed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) to do it. You can add specializations, not overloads.

Comment: ahhh yeah okay so i was just about to update this, it wont let me overload operator<< outside of std??? i keep getting this huge compiler error on standards. Even having it overloaded with the friend specifier inside the class def.

Comment: It should be `operator<<`, not `std::operator<<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace std {
    class Point;
    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os , vector<Point>& pointvect);
}
```

declares a class `std::Point`. Probably the declaration you've given for `Point` is not declared in the `std` namespace, thus they are different types.

Secondly, you can't declare a `std::vector` of an incomplete type and lastly there is no need to place `operator<<` in the `std` namespace, the compiler will pick the correct function by [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

---

Just place your `operator<<` in the same namespace as `Point` and after the full declaration of `Point` and it should work.

Comment: Note that there are two `operator<<` there. The first one takes `Point`, the second one takes a `std::vector` of them.

Comment: @Evg Yep, and even one that takes a vector of `std::Point`.